# rails installer package

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use rails on windows, I had problem while using it on windows. So now I have thought of using a prebuilt package like instant rails.  But as all we know , instantrails is fairly old. And it is long time when an update came , I think in 2008? I have also seen a latest release there named rails installer but it don't have seems to have MySQL. I am from PHP background and wonder that how can sql lite give all that which MySQL can? As I am more familiar with MySQL. So is there any other installer that I can use? I have seen another name "Ruby Stack" so is that all for rails 3 that instant rails had for old version?

Answer (score 1):

http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack

Answer (score 0):

[RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) is quite good and up-to-date. If you need MySQL you can install [XAMPP for Windows](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) too.

**Edit:**
This is how the database.yml should be configured in your applications:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  database: yourdatabase
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: so I need to use separate MySQL by some thing like xampp? and then how will it configure? Will I just give localhost for host in settings of rails?

Comment: Exactly. I added an example of a database configuration file.